# Replace HTML Form Element?

Tags: regex, vb.net, replace

I have this HTML code:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE></TITLE>

</HEAD>

<BODY>

<form action="http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl" method="post">
<input id="email" class="text" type="text" size="20" value="Enter your best email" name="email" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter your best email';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Enter your best email') {this.value = '';}" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_web_form_id" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="meta_split_id" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="listname" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="meta_adtracking" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="meta_message" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="meta_required" value="email">
<input type="hidden" name="meta_tooltip" value="">
<div style="padding-top:5px;">
<center><input class="button1" id="submit" type="image" src="red_getwaitinglist.png" name="submit" value="Get Instant Access"/></center>
</div>
</form>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

and I'm using this Function to replace the  element using RegEx:

```
Function StripTags(ByVal html As String, ByVal replace As String) As String
    Return Regex.Replace(html, "<form.+?</form>", replace)
End Function
```

but it doesn't seem to work. It returns the same code (no replacement).

I don't know much of regex so I'm assuming the RegEx syntax might be wrong. 
Can someone help me with that or show me where I'm wrong?

Comment: You should use the HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: You should use the HtmlAgilityPack because there are very serious problems involved with using regular expressions with HTML. Just Don't Do That.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thank you guys, I'm just taking a look at HtmlAgilityPack and I think you pointed me in the right direction. I never heard of it before so thanks both of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append the RegexOption `Singleline`. Without this `.` will not match newlines.

```
Return Regex.Replace(html, "<form.+?</form>", replace, RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

See [RegexOptions Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) for more details.